# How to create a "fill-up" animation in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to create a "fill-up" animation on a shape in Android. It should start being completely invisible and then gradually "fill up" from the bottom like this:
[image]

What I am specifically trying to animate is a circle such as this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">

   <solid 
       android:color="#666666"/>

   <size 
       android:width="120dp"
       android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

I have checked out the AlphaAnimation, RotateAnimation, ScaleAnimation and TranslateAnimation (sublasses of Animation) but I can't find a way to use them for this.

Comment: @Wallén Just checked the image seems to deleted. please upload a new image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I eventually solved it:

I included this library from github https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress which contains a circular progress bar (CircleProgress). I added a countdowntimer to gradually increase the "progress" it is displaying

Here is the code:

```
final CircleProgress circularProgress =(CircleProgress)findViewById(R.id.circleProgress);

//Hides the text and the part of the circle which should not be shown
circularProgress.setUnfinishedColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
circularProgress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));

//Makes the circle red
circularProgress.setFinishedColor("#FF0000");

final int timeToCountDownMilis = 10000;
circularProgress.setMax(timeToCountDownMilis);

//Initiates and starts the countdowntimer which gradually increases the "progress" in the progress bar
new CountDownTimer(timeToCountDownMilis,70){

    onTick(long milisUntilFinished){
       circularProgress.setProgress(timeToCountDownMilis-(int)milisUntilFinished);
    }

    onFinish(){
    }
}.start();
```

Thanks to Stan for pointing me to circular progress bars!

Answer (score 2):

You could dig deep in Animations, like drawPath etc. What I should do in this case is simplier a bit:
-place a full red circle on a screen
-put a View with white bg over it (like a square), covering all the circle
-animate that white square View moving up revealing your circle
You could use a simple transition animation to do it.
That way it gonna looks like a filling animation you want.
Well, my answer was given following images you provide and it covers the target good enough. But if you wish something like a progress bar looking so, you should visit https://github.com/snowdream/awesome-android and check circular progress bar libs there, at least you'll maybe lern how to achieve your goal Or find out its already done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This seems like a good idea. The only problem is that there will be content above my circle that such a square will would hide...